# Count the number of customers group by first letter

Tags: sql, count

I have to get the  number of customers by the first alphabet of last name(for all 26 alphabets) from a database of Customers with Lastname column.
I want the output to be something like this:

```
Alphabet Count
A          34
B          23
C           9
D           67
```

and so on

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server and MySQL

```
SELECT LEFT(colName,1) as Alphabet,COUNT(*) as CountNumber
FROM tableName
GROUP BY LEFT(colName,1)
```

If you want count list for all 26 alphabets , first you will have to take a temporary table and populate it with all the 26 alphbets and then do a LEFT JOIN with above resultset.

```
 CREATE TABLE #AlphabetTable(Alphabet CHAR(1));

 INSERT INTO #AlphabetTable VALUES('A');
 INSERT INTO #AlphabetTable VALUES('B');
 .
 .
 .
 INSERT INTO #AlphabetTable VALUES('Z');
```

Then do below query which shows count as zero if no column value is present for particular alphabet.

```
 SELECT a.Alphabet,COALESCE(CountNumber,0)
 FROM #AlphabetTable a
 LEFT JOIN
          (
            SELECT LEFT(colName,1) as Alphabet,COUNT(*) as CountNumber
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY LEFT(colName,1)

          ) t
   ON a.Alphabet=t.Alphabet
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Table CLIENT with CLI_ID as unique identifier column and CLI_NAME as column

select LEFT(CLI_NAME,1) FirstLetter, count(CLI_ID) Cnt   from CLIENT
group by LEFT(CLI_NAME,1)
order by Cnt desc